# Data validation lost when I copy a worksheet to another workbook

Tags: validation, excel, vba

I have an Excel 2010 workbook that contains a number(18) of worksheets. I have one sheet named "Data" that contains a number of named ranges that I use in data validation lists on the main worksheet for the new book. To keep users from corrupting the source worksheets I have added macros that create a new workbook and copy the appropriate worksheets to the new workbook including the "Data" worksheet.

When the user attempt to use the new workbook the data validation lists do not contain data. When I look at the data validation box the correct name range is there. However, on exit of the dialog box, I get an error message "you may not use references to other workbook for Data Validation Criteria"

I feel that I need to change the name range reference (=TestResultName) where TestResultName is a name range on the data worksheet.

Comment: You could try copying the whole workbook, which will keep the references within it, and then deleting the unneeded worksheets.

Comment: Thank you Doug G. I did get this to work by coping the workbook and deleting the un-needed worksheets. I had a lot of workbook protections on the master that needed to be changed to get this to work. I would like to see an answer using the original format.

Comment: Can you use the `ActiveWorkbook.Connections` command to check your validations? If you can sort their names out, you could also change them