# Data validations lost when copying worksheet using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

Problem: I am having a problem with data validations not copying to the copied worksheet when a worksheet is copied using a macro. Is there any way to do this using my current code?

Yes, I am also aware that there is a similar question (Here: [Data validation lost when I copy a worksheet to another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006556/data-validation-lost-when-i-copy-a-worksheet-to-another-workbook)) but it isn't quite the same issue and does not yet at this time have an answer. Any help to get these data validations to copy along with the data would be much appreciated and will save hours of needless repetitive work.

Edit: This code is in the "ThisWorkbook" section of my workbook.

My code is as follows:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim sName As String
Dim bValidName As Boolean
Dim i As Long

bValidName = False

Do While bValidName = False
    sName = InputBox("Please name this new worksheet:", "New Sheet Name", Sh.Name)
        If Len(sName) > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To 7
            sName = Replace(sName, Mid(":\/?*[]", i, 1), " ")
        Next i
        sName = Trim(Left(WorksheetFunction.Trim(sName), 31))
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)") Then bValidName = True
    End If
Loop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsTemp = wb.Sheets("TEMPLATE")

wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetVisible
wsTemp.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = sName
Sh.Delete
wsTemp.Visible = xlSheetHidden   'Or xlSheetVeryHidden

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

' Call Sort_Active_book
' Call Rebuild_TOC
```

Comment: if the validations won't copy over, one possible solution may be to store the details of your validations (cell address, validation formula, etc) in "reference" worksheet and then create a sub procedure to build the validations for each new sheet based on the information you store in the reference worksheet validation table. That way all you need to do is manage the table and the validations will update accordingly.

Comment: This is a good idea but possibly to your surprise this is a maintenance work sheet for a template worksheet I have and this is the "reference" worksheet you may be suggesting already, there is no data stored on this worksheet. What do you think may be a good direction to head from here?

Comment: if Gary's Student's post below doesn't help, create *another* reference worksheet with the data validation table and information on it. That's the beauty (and perhaps curse) of Excel. You can have several design elements :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Creating an additional reference worksheet does not seem like the route to take because I am only wanting to copy and paste the data validations and there is no data on the "TEMPLATE (Maint.)" worksheet, this worksheet essentially is the reference sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy a worksheet and retain DV.  This example:

- Activates *Sheet1*
- creates a simple DV on *Sheeet1*
- copies *Sheet1* to the end of the workbook

```
Sub Macro2()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "alpha"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "beta"
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "gamma"
    Range("B1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$D$1:$D$3"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
End Sub
```

This is recorded code run on a new, empty workbook on a Win 7/Excel 2007 system.

Can you replicate my result ??

If my code works on your system, begin by trying to mimic your VBA code manually with the recorder turned.  Then take your recorded code and modify it to include non-recordable parts, *(like the `InputBox` statements)*.

Comment: Although this is a perfect example to help me walk myself though VBA code by using the macro recorder, the problem lays with me not knowing Visual Basic's syntax, methods or many of it's best practices; this includes when to avoid and when to use Select.
PS: I was able to replicate your result from the code you provided